# error: assignment of data-member ‘RootBoxT<CORE::DoubleWrapper>::innerBox_’ in read-only structure

Tags: c++, constants, structure, readonly

I encountered an error as the topic says: `assignment of data-member ‘RootBoxT<CORE::DoubleWrapper>::innerBox_’ in read-only structure`. I "might" know why does this happen, but I need to learn more about the rules.

I made all instances for `RootBoxT` as `const`, and the member variable `*innerBox_` of class `RootBoxT` is also `const` type. In one of the methods of class `RootBoxT`, I need to update the `*innerBox_`, so I called `delete` to free the memory of `innerBox_` and assigned it with another const pointer.

My questions is that:

1. Is this the right method, that when I need to update the value of a const pointer, I just delete it and assign it with another const pointer?
2. Is this error cause by the fact that the instance of `RootBoxT` is `const` but one of the methods changed the place that a member variable points to? If not, why does it happen? If so, should I just change these instances to non-const?

I really messed up with `const` keyword for my current project, as I'm rather new to C++. Thanks.

Comment: You can't *update the value* of a `const` object. `const` means you can't change it. Also, you'd better post your code, because it is not clear wether you are talking about const pointers or pointers to const objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
struct S
{
   int * i;
};
```

and a `const S` object (`s`), the pointer `s.i` is `const` but not the `int` it points to (`*s.i`). This means you can write:

```
*s.i = 4;
delete s.i;
```

but not:

```
s.i = new int (5);   // illegal
int * j = 0;
s.i = j;             // illegal
```

because that would modify the *pointer* value, not what it points to.